# Published Facebook app up doesn't show up

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have published my Facebook app (related to messaging) and it was confirmed, however, users cannot find it in Facebook's search bar and in apps category. Is there anything I am missing? I tried to search for the solution in Facebook's documentations and etc, but did not succeed.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: afaik it takes a while to show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messenger bots/apps don't show up in the search, but the Facebook Page you linked your app to. For Messenger bots and businesses there's the Discover section in the Messenger app itself.